# How to apply changes made by fdisk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04

I have a SSD, allocated 100G for Ubuntu and 150 G for Windows 10, then I decided to increase the volume of Ubuntu. In Windows, using EaseUS, I freed 50G, then in Ubuntu I ran `fdisk`. It showed up 50G as a free disk. Then I hit `Resize` and it offered `150G` as I guess calculated based on my free disk. I said `yes` and then selected `Write` and then rebooted the system.

`fdisk -l /dev/sda` shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SX900     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6ef3495a

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 295313090 294594243 140.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       295313408 296364031   1050624   513M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda4       296366078 500117503 203751426  97.2G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       296366080 500117503 203751424  97.2G 83 Linux
```

So far, so good. However I'm not sure if the changes has applied because when I tried to check free disk using `System Monitor` it shows 100G and 97% used:

[image]

So, did I increase the volume? How do I apply changes made by fdisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you haven't changed the size. You seem to have 3 "main" partions:

- sda 1+2  windows partition
- sda 3+4  Fat32 partition
- sda 5    Linux partition

sda 5 is shown with 97.2 GB. The sum of all is around 350 gb. So where should that additional space come from?

I would advise to use `gparted` for resizing partions. I've used it even on devices that had a windows partition. It always worked.

Comment: Ooop! right! Does `Gparted` need USB startup? if so, I must create it

Comment: Yep, you can use any live usb, some have gparted already installed. Or use a live ubuntu and install it

Comment: Can I free again the disk space of the Windows drive and add it to linux?

Comment: Ya, make sure that the pagefile.sys in windows is removed. There are instructions how to do that. without it, it won't work

Comment: Another question, I ran Gparted, and shrunk the Windows partition, it shows an unallocated part, but it's not beside the linux partition, so I guess I can't join them. Should I create a new disk by it and then move it and adjoin it to linux?

Comment: [google is you friend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483769/gparted-how-to-merge-unallocated-space-with-a-partition)